# Force change in commiter's email

Tags: git, gitlab

I made a commit with the wrong email "email@gmail.com" and when I tried to push the commit, It failed for the following reason

> remote: GitLab: Committer's email 'email@gmail.com' does not follow the pattern '@company.fr$'
>
> To gitlab.com:xxxxxx.git
>    ! [remote rejected]     xxxx -> xxxx (pre-receive hook declined)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxx'

I forced a changed in the commit's email with the command:

> git commit --amend --reset-author

I forced the change in the email address to the right address "email@company.fr" and the logs show that the change has been effective

But when I try to push (with --force) the commit, I still have to same error above.

If you have any idea why it doesn't work and how I can force it, I would gladly welcome it

Thank you

Comment: If the first push was rejected, you should not need `--force` on the second push, as the upstream repository never acquired the commit you've shoved aside in favor of the corrected one. This particular error might occur if you made *two or more* commits with incorrect authors, and this `git push` is trying to push *all* of them. That is, you've fixed the last commit in a chain of at least two commits, leaving at least one still incorrect. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

I have also seen this problem with Bitbucket, and I also don't know why it happens (it should not based on my understanding).  What I have found works is correcting the user email profile locally in Git, and then recommitting.  Try the following:

```
# from your feature branch
git branch backup                         # create backup branch
git reset --hard HEAD~1                   # remove the problem commit
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of HEAD of backup> # cherry-pick back the commit
git push origin feature
```

When you cherry-pick back your commit, you are essentially creating a brand new commit, with the correct email address the first time around.  I have seen this approach work with Bitbucket, and it is worth trying with Gitlab.